# Labeled break statement issue

Tags: java

I am using following code for my test automation selenium webdriver

```
List<WebElement> lViewLink = driver.findElements(By.xpath(aaObject.getProperty("aa_ViewLink")));

Viewloop:
for(WebElement view: lViewLink) {
    view.click();
    String sWizardHeader = driver.findElement(By.xpath(aaObject.getProperty("aa_NewAAWizard"))).getText();
    if(sWizardHeader.equals("Auto Attendant Wizard")) {
        break Viewloop;
    } else {
        clickObject(aaObject.getProperty("aa_Close"));
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

but loop continues till lViewLink length, what is the problem in the code?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen the `Viewloop:` outside of your code block. Try to debug it - does it enter the if statement?

Comment: Btw, there is no reason for a labeled break statement.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that `String sWizardHeader` is not equal `"Auto Attendant Wizard"`. Could you provide output `System.out.println(sWizardHeader)` before if/else statement?

Comment: The "Auto Attendant Wizard" is heading for unused wizard, if the wizard is already configured then it will be like "Test details" where Test is name given to the wizard.